# ActivePerl Installation error

Tags: perl, activeperl

Hi, I tried to install ActivePerl on Linux ( 64 bit ). I got the following error.

perl/bin/perl: /lib64/libc.so.6: version `GLIBC_2.14' not found (required by perl/bin/perl)

Any one faced this issue?

Thanks,
Chaitanya

Comment: OS is Redhat Linux

Comment: Why not just use the version of perl that comes with Redhat?

Comment: Currently I am working on Migration project. So lot of scripts are using ActivePerl so I want to install this.

Comment: As long as you use the same version number, your scripts will work fine on non-ActivePerl. ActivePerl is almost exclusively used on Windows because most *nix operating systems (including Mac OS X) come with perl pre-installed. If you want to install a different version of perl on *nix, [perlbrew](https://perlbrew.pl/) is the easiest option.

Comment: Thanks for the information. I am trying with non-ActivePerl. Looks like it is working but some of the modules are missing like sendmail. Please let me know how to install particular module "Mail::Sendmail". I am new to perl.

Comment: If you're using the system perl, it's best to use the package manager. On Redhat that would be yum or dnf. Package names have the form perl-Module-Name, so to install Mail::Sendmail, run `yum install perl-Mail-Sendmail`. Not all CPAN modules are available as RPMs, though, so I would recommend installing another version of perl in your home directory using perlbrew; then you can install modules using the cpan command, e.g. `cpan Mail::Sendmail`.

Comment: Thanks for info. Yes lot of modules are missing. I am not sure what all the modules need to install. The project is Migrating AIX server to Linux.

Comment: Right now I am getting the following error:Loading DB routines from perl5db.pl version 1.32
Editor support available.

Enter h or `h h' for help, or `man perldebug' for more help.

BEGIN not safe after errors--compilation aborted at /usr/share/perl5/Carp/Heavy.pm line 11, <DATA> line 522.
Compilation failed in require at /usr/share/perl5/Carp.pm line 33, <DATA> line 522.
Debugged program terminated.  Use q to quit or R to restart,
  use o inhibit_exit to avoid stopping after program termination,
  h q, h R or h o to get additional info.

Comment: which one need to install: yum list perl-* | grep -i carp
perl-Carp-Always.noarch        0.09-2.el6   rhel-x86_64-server-6-datacenter-epel
perl-Carp-Assert.noarch        0.20-4.el6   rhel-x86_64-server-6-datacenter-epel
perl-Carp-Assert-More.noarch   1.12-6.el6   rhel-x86_64-server-6-datacenter-epel
perl-Carp-Clan.noarch          6.03-2.el6   rhel-x86_64-server-6-datacenter
perl-Carp-Fix-1_25.noarch      1.000001-3.el6
perl-Test-Carp.noarch          0.2-2.el6    rhel-x86_64-server-6-datacenter-epel

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sounds like you are on an older version linux with its corresponding Glibc that is not new enough to run the perl binary. Updating your OS would be ideal, but if that isn't possible, you can try other methods, note some of these can be a bit tricky.

RedHat has an article on upgrading glibc:  http://developers.redhat.com/blog/2016/02/17/upgrading-the-gnu-c-library-within-red-hat-enterprise-linux/

A previous issue (was on ORACLE linux) sounds like it might be related is here: 
https://community.activestate.com/node/12912

Comment: Hi ToofHurtz, Thanks for your reply. May I know what are those other methods. I think its not possible to update the OS.

Comment: Upgrade the glibc as per the red hat article. Also what version of Perl are you running?